# Sort 2 Rows decending

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Thank you for your time**
So i have a table where i keep trak of sports teams.
|[image]

First i would like to sort by point but if 2 teams have the same points the one with the better Goal difference should be on Top
i plan in having a max of ~50 teams. 
I enter my scorelines on a different sheet and add the points + goal difference to the table

I know i have to sort the table with :

```
function onEdit(e) {My Code}
```

But i dont have a idea on how to sort my table. 
I already tried 2 variants but either they dont work or I did someting wrong

```
.sort(Points).sort(Goal difference);
```

and

```
.sort(Goal difference).sort( Points);
```

If anyone has an idea that would be great

Comment: look at Class Range Method sort. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object)

Comment: As @Cooper mentioned, the sort method will be helpful for your purpose, can you please confirm that?

Comment: Yes it worked thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The method sort(sortSpecObj) answers this question

In order to have this post better documented, when it comes to order rows by column the correct way to do this is, i.e.:

```
var range = sheet.getRange("A1Notation");

// Sorts descending by column B, then ascending by column A
// Note the use of an array
range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: false}, {column: 1, ascending: true}]);
```

### Reference

- [Range.sort(...)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj)